# 3D interpolation of a volume with irregular upsampling

Tags: interpolation, upsampling

Given a collection of 2D slices which as a whole corresponds to a 3D volume (medical image of an organ), I only take specific slices (i.e. I replace the ones I dont want with zeros) and so, I end up with a 3D matrix of same shape e.g. 64x64x40 and it is "like" if I had an irregular sampling. I now would like to interpolate to have a full 64x64x40 matrix.

I think it looks like a traditionnal upsampling (e.g like if I had these 40-n slices and upsampled with 0s but irregularily. Now I would like to interpolated this irregular upsampling. Any ideas/references? I am having trouble to find.

Comment: Yes it's interesting. Basically it looks like a nonuniform sampling along vertical z direction (assuming, slices parallel to x-y plane). It's also related with missing samples. Medical imaging is an extensive field, with classical CT having a leading role. A lot of literature exist on every aspect of CT. You can search IEEE first.